# radiobutton disable after 10 seconds

Tags: php, javascript, radio-button

I have a problem with disabling my radiobuttons.

I generate some options from my mysql db with php like this:

```
 <input type=\"radio\" name=\"answer\" id=\"answer\" value=\"".$inhAnswer['id']."\"/>
```

No problems yet :)

Then i use a countdown script for example 10 seconds. That is working too. Then after the 10 seconds i want to disable the radiobuttons. I use this:

```
document.form1.answer[0].disabled = true;
```

This is working. But what i need and i can't figure this out, is to disable ALL buttons. Now i can only disable the first one. And i know that document.form1.answer[1] etc will disable the others but i don't know how many radiobuttons will be used.

So how can i let the script disable all answer radiobuttons at once?

Cheers,

Toby

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but i don't know how many radiobuttons will be used

The total number is: `document.form1.answer.length;`

Docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length

Comment: Thanks Hakre

This is what i do now and this is working:
    
    var i=0;
   for (i=0;i<=document.Question.answer.length;i++)
   {
   document.Question.answer[i].disabled = true;
   }

Answer (score 0):

i am not very sure but you can try something like this.

```
var children = document.form1.answer;

for(var i=0; i<children.length; i++) {
     children[i].disabled = true;
}
```